# Installing Broadcom 14e4:4365 rev 01 drivrt

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

i have installed Ubuntu 15.04 64bit on my laptop (lenovo e531) alongside with windows 8.1 and while trying to install wifi driver
i found this method [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
but when i try this command :`sudo "apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
it gives me this error :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it

Just go to system setting then chose software and updates 
and make sure your choices are like the screenshot :

[image]

I believe the problem was that I checked the installable from cd/dvd room and 
"download from" I chose my country which I changed to main server.